# Way to update 3 variables depending on a fourth in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, max

I have defined three variables `a,b,c` before a while loop, then compute a new var  `d`.

I want to get rid of the biggest value in the three vars `a,b,c` and then replace it with `d` value; So I can keep the smallest values in the thre original vars.

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 10;
While[ condition,

      compute d using  values of a b and c
      d = 4;      
      a = 1;
      b = 2;
      c = 4;  (*c = d *)


]
```

to do so I was think to get the max of the three vars and then update it depeneding wich has greatest value..

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 10;
d = 4;
temp  = Max[a, b];
maxim = Max[c, temp];
a = a; (*did not change*)
b = b; (*did not change*)
c = d = 4 (*changed!!*)
```

So after that a new iteraion will occur and update the three vars...

Comment: So you have a list of three variables with numeric values and you want to replace the largest member in the list with a new value?

Comment: Is it important that your variable are individual, named symbols (`a`, `b`, `c`) or can they be a list such as `{1, 5, 0}` (of which individual elements can be accessed with `Part`)?

Comment: well, the variables `a,b and c` are defined before a while loop, then will be computed inside a while loop also the fourth var, and then all must be updated

Comment: Also, I am confused by "most near to the new value 5" which I believe would be 1, rather than 10.

Comment: yes, let me explain it the right way, I want to update three vars, and the biggest value, so suppose I have  a=1,b=2,c=40, then a fourth var d=5, so I will have a=1,b=2,c=5, because a,b are near from new value d

Comment: So you want to replace the value that **is not near** the new `d` value?

Comment: Exactly, sorry if I did not explain it right

Comment: This is still not clear.  5 - 0 == 5; 10 - 5 == 5.  How are you defining near?  Are you looking for a cluster of values?  Sequential order?

Comment: Get rid of the biggest value, and the variable wich is the biggest is replaced with the value of `d`, so ,I keep the three samllest values

Comment: Please update your question to make this clear.

Comment: @cMinor I remember you from MATLAB tag, and I see a heavy influence of that in your Mathematica code. Although procedural code might be useful when beginning to learn Mathematica, I would strongly suggest picking up more idiomatic ways of doing things in Mathematica along the way (see our answers for some approaches that you wouldn't have seen in other languages). It'll surely help you a lot as you delve deeper into it. In the mean time, I think all three of us who have answered would appreciate some feedback...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is as follows:

```
Clear@updateList
SetAttributes[updateList, HoldFirst]    
updateList[list_, value_] := 
     Module[{listMax = Max@list}, 
      list = (list /. listMax -> value);]
```

Now if I define variables as in your case and use the function:

```
a = 1; b = 10; c = 0;
updateList[{a,b,c},5];
{a,b,c}

Out[1]= {1, 5, 0}
```

You can see that the variable `b`, which was the largest has been replaced with the new value.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right, I don't need `ReleaseHold`. `HoldFirst` is only an attribute of `updateList` and is used in the first instance of `list`. In the second and third, `list` is an argument of `ReplaceAll` and `Max` respectively, and hence, that attribute doesn't hold.

Comment: Delete your comment before Leonid sees it.  He'll tell everyone! :->

Comment: This just isn't fair. You're now over 50 upvotes ahead of me. I may have to turn to the dark side to combat this ...

Comment: left you in the dust, did I? :D It's actually the first time I've ever come close to 100 upvotes in 30 days in mma and _actually_ close to a silver. When I started out, I thought I'd have a gold in MATLAB by now, but looks like I lost interest there. I haven't seriously answered there since June (so more time for mma :D). But seriously, I see myself getting _very_ busy in the next couple of months, so run tortise, run!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm about to be extremely busy myself, so catching you is going to be hard, despite your short legs ... :)  I also have never had 100 upvotes in 30 days, period.  But, I haven't participated nearly as much as you.

Comment: @belisarius I saw that a few days ago. Must be an evil one, as he knows all weird languages that I've never heard of. Technically, he's been around for 2 yrs and I went through some of his old posts and he's had the "Yoda" pseudonym  for all this while and so I'm the duplicate...

Comment: @yoda Now I must be very careful when downvoting you. I don't want to hurt innocents :D

Answer (score 6):

If you can accept the values in a list (array) rather than individual named Symbols, and if you really mean "most near" rather than greatest, then you may do something like this:

```
vars = {1, 10, 0};

vars = ReplacePart[vars, Position[vars, Nearest[vars, 5][[1]]] -> 5];

vars
```

```
(* Out=  {5, 10, 0} *)
```

This also assumes that values are unique, *or* that you want to replace all values that match (such as if there is more than one `1` in the list in this example).

If you always what to replace the greatest value, then you could `Max[vars]` rather than `Nearest`.

---

In light of the updated problem description, I propose:

```
vars = {1, 10, 0};
d = 5;

vars = With[{m = Max[vars]}, If[d < m, vars /. m -> d, vars]]
```

If you wish to automate this, you may use:

```
SetAttributes[repmax, HoldFirst]
repmax[s_Symbol, n_?NumericQ] := If[n < #, s = s /. # -> n]& @ Max@s
```

Now:

```
vals = {1, 10, 0};
repmax[vals, 5];

vals
```

```
{1, 5, 0}
```

```
vals = {1, 10, 0};
repmax[vals, 12];

vals
```

```
{1, 10, 0}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the best way to go about this problem,

```
a = 1; b = 10; c = 0;
Position[#, Max@#] &@{a, b, c}
{a, b, c} = ReplacePart[{a, b, c}, % -> 5]
```

You'd be better off defining your original values in as a list `abc = {1, 10, 0}` and then replacing the max element of the list. As I noticed Mr Wizard has just done in his answer.

You can also do something like

```
SetAttributes[ReplaceMax, HoldFirst]
ReplaceMax[list : {__Symbol}, val_] := Module[{pos},
  pos = Flatten@Position[#, Max@Select[#, N[#] \[Element] Reals &]]&@list;
  Do[Evaluate[(HoldPattern /@ Unevaluated@list)[[p]]] = val, 
     {p, pos}]]
```

Then

```
In[15]:= {a, b, c, d, e} = {1, 15, 6, 17 + I, x}; 
In[16]:= ReplaceMax[{a, b, c, d, e}, 5]
          {a, b, c, d, e}

Out[17]= {1, 5, 6, 17 + I, x}
```